# RET from procedure jumping to the start of the program?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

When I call a procedure it randomly it returns to the start of the program instead of to the following line as it should. This is what happens:

```
CALL calculator
; A

calculator PROC
  ; ...
RET               ; Jumpts to the start of the program instead of to point A
calculator ENDP
```

My theory is that the return address is probably stored in a register or something I'm randomly modifying but I don't know which one. Anyway, for any reason my procedure doesn't go to the next line. What can cause this to happen?

Comment: are you manipulating the stack (`SS:SP`) in any way?

Comment: yes, however the code should leave it as it found it at the start of the procedure. I'll check if the problem is there, probably is

Comment: The stack contains the return address, and the instruction pointer points to the next instruction. In your sample, you are not manipulating either. Is this example really sufficient for reproducing?

Comment: The procedure has more lines that I can fit in here. I think this problem is solved anyway. I just wanted to know where the return address was stored, how it worked. Maybe the question was badly phrased